# C++ Builder 2009 - Form Layout Not Refreshing on Build

Tags: compiler-construction, c++builder

Using C++ Builder 2009, Win 7.

I made form layout updates to several forms and did a clean, build and make on the project. Despite these commands, the layout still displays the old layout.

I'm curious if anyone has come across this and if there is a proper way to do this from the IDE. I'm going to manually delete all the obj files, etc in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I asked this question. I believe the root of the problem was a 3rd party component for translation. The component would pull the layout information and would only update the layout if you ran their "update language" utility. When the utility is runs, it updates the layouts in all of the languages. Needless to say, running that utility updates the layout.